# When should I use `export default`in JavaScript / TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

If we specify a default export:

```
export class Foo {}
export default Foo;
```

then we can omit curly braces during import (as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117231/154066)):

```
import { Foo } from "foo"; // becomes:
import Foo from "foo";
```

That's fine, but is there any non-stylistic reason to prefer one over the other in particular cases? For example, is there some convention, or is one incompatible with certain tools, or does one have a different meaning?

(Based on [this discussion](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/moduleimport#content-0) and others, my understanding is that `export default` might have arisen as a way of handling the export of a single, primary object (like `$`), which is now handled by `import * as foo from "foo"`. Also, it seems the default import syntax does not enforce consistent naming (`import fooAlias from "foo"`), while the standard import `import { fooAlias } from "foo"` would be a compilation error unless the alias was explicit (`Foo as fooAlias`). Apart from that, I haven't been able to find much information on when I should use one over the other.)

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be used when the module defines only a single object (or value in general). Notice that `import * as $ from "jquery";` would not work - you want `$` to be a function not a namespace object.

Comment: @Bergi right, but would omitting the default export and importing via `import { $ } from "jquery"` be any different? When would I use one over the other? Is `export default` ever required at all?

Comment: A default export is usually the most important value, i.e. the one used more frequently. The default export is just another named export with the special name `default`, so  `import { default as $ } from 'jquery'` is equivalent to `import $ from 'jquery'`.

Comment: @mk.: Using a named export is just more verbose (`import { jQuery as $ } …`), and you need to remember the name of the export - and repeat it, as it will be the same everywhere. No, default exports are nowhere required, they're just a convienience.

Answer (score 2):

There's no right or wrong here. I prefer to export one thing so default works for me most of the time. You can also use both too.

I tend to not use `default` when taking a more pure functional approach or writing a set of static util functions.

So when my module is really just a class, I like to use `default`. Notice I can still export other things.

```
export default class Foo {
}
```

// some util module

```
export function fooHelper() {
}
export function bazHelper() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

exporting default can allow you to rename the file on import so...

**foo.js**

```
export default class Foo{
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

can be `import Bar from './foo';` in another file, this could be useful if you're using a library and already have a class Foo defined.

You can also export a default and a non default such that:
`import Foo, { someVariable, someMethod } from './foo';`

Comment: This would be the sort of answer I'm looking for ("it allows us to alias"), but aliasing is also available without default exports: just write `import { Foo as fooAlias }...`. It's a bit longer, but that's ultimately just a stylistic difference...