# testing react component with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

Say I have the following component:

```
export default class CustomInput extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <input type='text' value={this.props.value || ''} onChange={this.props.changeHandler} placeholder={this.props.placeholderValue} />
    )
  }
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
  placeholderValue: PropTypes.string,
  changeHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Which I attempt to test as follows:

```
test('input renders correctly', () => {
    const handler = jest.fn()
    const display = shallow(<CustomInput value='foo' placeholderValue='bar' changeHandler={handler}/>)
    })
```

This fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'contextTypes' of undefined
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the problem was with my import. Specifically, removing the autoimport like so:

`import CustomInput from './index'`

rather than

`import {CustomInput} from './index'`

An explanation of what caused the problem in the first place would be more than welcome

Comment: read this one: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules

Comment: there are two types of export, `default` and `named`, you are exporting the comp `CustomInput` as default and importing as the named because of that the issue u was facing. default export can be only one but named can be any number. The way you wrote 2nd line is, it was searching for a name export but no named export is defined, so it throws the error :)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426521/what-export-default-do-in-jsx