# React Jest test with method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to write a jest test for a method defined in my React.Component class.

```
class Math extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}

sum(a, b){
  return a+b; 
}
export default Math;
```

and in my Jest file I am doing this:

```
import { Math } from './Math'

 describe('Math', () => {
 it('should add correctly', () => {
  const result = Math.sum(10, 10);
  expect(result).toEqual(20);
 }
```

But it gives me an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum' of undefined

How should I resolve this issue ? I did try to look it online but couldnt find the solution.

Comment: https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx

Check this mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're using `Math.sum(x,y)` as a static function instead of an Object reference.

You can change your function to:

```
static sum(a, b){
  return a + b; 
}
```

Object references call for you to pass variables to the constructor or dynamically assign them through a function.

```
let x, y;
class Math {
 //The constructor has optional parameters which default to 0. 
 constructor(first=0, second=0){
  this.x = first;
  this.y = second;
}

//Makes a sum with the variables passed through the constructor.
sum(){
 return x+y;
}

//sets the x value
changeX(num){ x = num; }

//returns the x value
getX(){ return x; }

//This function saves it to the object beforehand so you may retrieve it later. 
sumSaved(first, second){
  this.x = first;
  this.y = second;
return x + y;
} 

//Assigned through the constructor.
let foo = new Math(first:1,second:2);
foo.sum(); //returns 3 because 1+2=3
foo.changeX(2);
foo.sum(); //returns 4 because 2+2=4

//Assigned through a function.
let bar = new Math();
bar.sumSaved(4,6); //returns 10 and overwrites variables.
bar.getX(); //returns 4, because you saved it earlier.
```

See [here](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2015/02/02/static-members-in-es6.aspx) for information on static functions.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671636/3081794) on when you should use static functions.

Also, for information about default exports, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426521/what-does-export-default-do-in-jsx/36426988).

Comment: ok but in future I am thinking to add this instance as well inside the static method and you cannot access this inside a static method hence was trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `default` export while your import is named. Also: you are using the method `sum` on the class itself (like it was a static method) instead of an instance of the class.