# Type Error - Is Not a Constructor

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, transpiler

Wanted to instantiate a module within ES6 javascript and transpile to ES5. I am setting up a new class in my project which is es6 / webpack.
I have 2 files: 
track.js which has the following --

```
export default class Track {
  constructor() {
    this.o = {};
  }
}
```

The other is index.js --

```
import { Track } from './track';

const track = new Track();
console.log(track);
```

I am trying to have console log show an empty object.
Instead, I am getting --
*Uncaught TypeError: _track.Track is not a constructor*

Comment: import Track from './track'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're importing `Track` in `index.js`. You need to either import like this:

```
import Track from './track';
```

Or in `track.js` you need to export it like this:

```
export {Track}
```

Answer (score 12):

You're exporting `Track` as default, so you should use default import. Change

```
import { Track } from './track';
```

to

```
import Track from './track';
```

See [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

---

When you do `import { Track } from './track'` you're trying to access the `Track` property of the exported object (which is the Track class), which is undefined (so it's not a constructor).