# require working but import not working

Tags: es6-module-loader, es6-class, es6-modules

I have a actions.js file that is exporting actions like this

```
export var toggleTodo = (id) => {
  return {
    type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
    id
  }
}
```

but when i import it using es6 import i get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggleTodo' of undefined
```

but when i require it using common js require it works just fine! Can someone explain to me why is this happening, I mean i read these two are same things... Something seem to be different ?

```
// var actions = require('actions') working 
// dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id));

import actions from 'actions' //not working
dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several different forms of `import`, each doing slightly different thing. The one you are using

```
import actions from 'actions' //not working
```

is for importing [default export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript) from `actions` module. You can see  [complete list in MDN javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

It's not working because your `action.js` module probably does not have default export, and `actions` come as undefined.

The form that roughly corresponds to `require` call is this one:

```
import * as actions from 'actions';
```

it allows you to access all exported values as properties of `actions`:

```
dispatch(actions.toggleTodo(id));
```

or you can use named import  like this:

```
import {toggleTodo} from 'actions';
```

then you can use `toggleTodo` directly:

```
dispatch(toggleTodo(id));
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for Typeorm. 
import * as typeorm from 'typeorm'; 
still gives the same error.