# How to import module based dependencies for firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to organize my firebase cloud functions in specific files,
and currently, I have these 3:

- index.ts
- crypto.ts
- webscrape.ts

Inside of these files, I have functions that use specific dependencies that are needed nowhere else.

For example, in crypto.ts I need the crypto-js package to encrypt some user data and store it into the database.

So I am importing it like so:

```
import * as CryptoJS from "crypto-js";
```

as advised in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies#typescript

On the other hand, when I try to import puppeteer into webscrape.ts like this:

```
import * as puppeteer from"puppeteer-extra";
```

then calling `puppeteer.launch();` gives me an error :

`Property 'launch' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/Users/username/Desktop/project/firebasee/functions/node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index`")'

and it only works when I do `const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");`

What's the difference here?

My goal is to keep the dependencies of each functions and file/module as small as possible because I assume that this will also keep the size of each function container small (Is that even true?)


I didn't want to import everything to index.ts even when I trigger a function, that doesn't use this dependency at all.

So what is the correct way of handling these dependencies?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked [require working but import not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762352/require-working-but-import-not-working)?

Comment: I just read through it. So the answer is, that the import statement depends on the exports of the module?

Comment: Yes, I wasn't able to find any example that user ES6 imports with puppeteer

Comment: Okay, so it's fine to mix them as long as it works? 

Do you have any advice on the other parts of the question?

Comment: Have you tried `import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"` ?

Comment: No, but that seems to work. So ```import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"``` is the same as ```const puppeteer = required("puppeteer-extra")``` in its functionality?

Comment: Checkout [The difference between require(x) and "import x"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following import will get the default export from that package.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"
```

I looked for the [default export](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/blob/master/packages/puppeteer-extra/src/index.ts#L494) in the Github repository and found that.

```js
const defaultExport: PuppeteerExtra = (() => {
  return new PuppeteerExtra(...requireVanillaPuppeteer())
})()

export default defaultExport
```

They have mentioned both ES6 import and require methods [here](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/blob/master/packages/puppeteer-extra/src/index.ts#L484).

```js
// javascript import
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')

// typescript/es6 module import
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra'
```

You can read more about `import` on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Comment: I just tried to convert my ts files to js with "tsc" and got the error 
```Module '"puppeteer"' has no exported member 'FetcherOptions'
export { FetcherOptions } from 'puppeteer';``` so ```import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"``` does not seem to work

Comment: @Christian Can you share a screenshot of error? Also can you hover on `puppeteer` in `import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"` and share what it is? It's interface.

Comment: @Christian looking into... I also got `'headless' does not exist in type 'LaunchOptions'` along with those 2 which apparently had an [issue](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/426) in Github

Comment: There are a few bugs with the types: https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/issues/433

Comment: Hmm pretty confusing. I guess I will use whatever import method works then. Thank you!

Comment: @Christian so the correct way actually is to use `import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra"` however there are some broken types.. I have tried using several older version but was not able to get a working combination.