# React Native Element type is invalid expected a string but got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm following a course on react-native and I just ran into this error when trying to add a modal component to a page:

Element type is invalid: expected a string(for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Here's my code:

EmployeeEdit.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Communications from 'react-native-communications';
import { employeeUpdate, employeeSave, employeeReset } from '../actions';
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Confirm } from './common';
import EmployeeForm from './EmployeeForm';


class EmployeeEdit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showModal : false};

    this.onButtonPress = this.onButtonPress.bind(this);
    this.onTextPress = this.onTextPress.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    _.each(this.props.employee, (value, prop) => {
      this.props.employeeUpdate({prop, value});
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.employeeReset();
  }

  onButtonPress(){
    const { name, phone, shift } = this.props;
    this.props.employeeSave({ name, phone, shift, uid: this.props.employee.uid });
  }

  onTextPress(){
    const { name, phone, shift } = this.props;
    Communications.text(phone, `Hello ${name}, your upcoming shift is on ${shift}`);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Card>
        <EmployeeForm {...this.props} />
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={this.onTextPress}>
            Text Schedule
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={()=> this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal })}>
            Fire Employee
          </Button>
        </CardSection>
        <Confirm
          visible={this.state.showModal}
        >
          Are you sure you want to fire this employe?
        </Confirm>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const {name, phone, shift} = state.employeeForm;
  return {name, phone, shift};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  employeeUpdate,
  employeeSave,
  employeeReset
})(EmployeeEdit);
```

Confirm.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Modal } from 'react-native';
import { CardSection } from './CardSection';
import { Button } from './Button';

const Confirm = ({ children, visible, onAccept, onDecline }) => {
  const { containerStyle, textStyle, cardSectionStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      transparent
      animationType='slide'
      onRequestClose={() => {}}
    >
      <View style={containerStyle}>
        <CardSection style={cardSectionStyle}>
          <Text style={textStyle}>
            {children}
          </Text>
        </CardSection>

        <CardSection>
          <Button onPress={onAccept}>Yes</Button>
          <Button onPress={onDecline}>No</Button>
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const styles = {
  cardSectionStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  textStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: 40
  },
  containerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    position: 'relative',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
};

export default { Confirm };
```

The error only occurs when I add the confirm component to EmployeeEdit. When I remove the confirm component at the bottom the error goes away. Is there some error in my confirm component?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

at the bottom of Confirm.js it should be

```
export { Confirm };
```

not

```
export default { Confirm };
```

Answer (score 5):

When you're importing *Confirm* using curly braces

```
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Confirm } from './common';
```

make sure you're not exporting it using *default* like what you did:

```
export default { Confirm };
```

because once you use
*default* syntax, it doesn't require curly braces syntax when importing.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid the flower braces in all.

Do this.

In your Confirm.js

```
export default Confirm
```

In your EmployeeEdit.js

```
import Confirm from './Confirm'
```

As you see, I have omitted the braces. According to the ES6 Documentation, if a module defines a default export, then you can import the default export without the use of curly braces. Refer here: [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)