# Export default was not found

Tags: javascript, import, module, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I have a Vue 2 project, and I've written a simple function for translating months in dates, which I would like to import in one of my components, but I'm getting an error:

> export 'default' (imported as 'translateDate') was not found in '@/utils/date-translation'

The relative file path from the src folder is correct, and I am exporting the function like this:

```
export function translateDate(date) {
  // my code
}
```

And then I am importing it in the component like this:

```
import translateDate from '@/utils/date-translation'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `export default function...` and see answers to [What is "export default" in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* You are trying to import the default export of a module which does not have a default export. The module only has a named export, `translateDate`. You should have a look at the accepted answer of [When should I use curly braces for ES6 import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36795819/218196)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to specify `default` explicitly:

```
export default function translateDate(date) {
   ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It was caused by a Visual Studio shortcut I was using in my .jsx components and pages. I used rafc(ReactArrowFunctionComponent) instead of rafce(ReactArrowFunctionExportComponent). all errors fixed now. rafc didn't have    
export default Component.

Answer (score 89):

In my case I had to remove '{' and '}' arround the imported component :

```js
import { CustomComponent } from './CustomComponent';
```

with

```js
import CustomComponent from './CustomComponent';
```

Comment: And I had to add the `{}` to get rid of the message

Comment: Worked for me as well. But why?

Comment: I removed {} but I do not know why this solves this issue, I am using Laravel8 and vue 2.

Comment: i am using react, this worked for me

Comment: Reason for why this works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import

Answer (score 57):

Either specify `default` as mentioned above, or if you're trying to export multiple items from the same file you need to import them with curly brackets.

So you would have:

```
export function doWork(){}
export const myVariable = true;
```

And then you'd import them in a separate file as:

```
import { doWork, myVariable} from "./myES6Module"
```

Comment: When I use the code you provided, I have this issue :
"export 'default' (imported as 'doWork') was not found in './mymodule'

Comment: That's because you didn't export the thing you wanted to export in your module, or you're using a different name for it. When using named exports you need to use the same name in both files.

Comment: What if my function looks like this : export const function = (arg) => { }

Comment: I use curly brases, and exported the function. still getting this error

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have two files with the same name.For example, "test.vue" and "test.js"

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using

```
   export function translateDate(date) {
  // my code
}
```

use

```
     function translateDate(date){
         //code
          }

export default translateDate;
```

it worked for me...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set symlink setting in vue.config.js

```
config.resolve.symlinks(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i changed my code to this:

```
const registerUsers = (users) => {
    return http.post(`${config.toplearnapi}/api/register`, 
                     JSON.stringify(users));
};

export default registerUsers;
```

and when i imported this function i removed the braces which was around it:
this is the correct one:

```
import registerUsers from "../services/userServices";
```