# How to use an external array in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component

I've been trying to use an external array in my VueJs code, but I've been running into problems

Here's my code:

```
import iconsData from 'components/iconsData.js';
  export default{
    data(){
      return{
        activeIcon: '',
        icons : iconsData
      }
    },
    methods: {
      consoleIcons(){
        console.log(this.icons)
      }
    }
  }
```

iconsData.js is:

```
export const iconsData = [
   {"name": "material-icons"},
   {"name": "eva-icons"},
]
```

but all I get is a warning:

```
export 'default' (imported as 'iconsData') was not found in 'components/iconsData.js' (possible exports: iconsData)
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export default was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995136/export-default-was-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is tied to the import. Currently, iconsData.js exports an object { iconsData: [...] }. Thus, you need to be more specific about what exactly you are trying to import:

```js
import { iconsData } from 'components/iconsData.js';
```

Alternatively, this would also work:

```js
export default [
   {"name": "material-icons"},
   {"name": "eva-icons"},
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).