# Using crypto-js in React

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, cryptojs

I generated an app using `create-react-app` and I want to use
[crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)
I am getting the following error

> `crypto.sha256() is not a function`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You gotta install crypto-js using

```
npm install crypto-js
```

In your js files, you have to import module you wanna use

```
import sha256 from 'crypto-js/sha256';
```

Now you can use those functions

```
sha256(nonce + message);
```

You have do define `message` and `nonce` before this

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain to me why doesn't `import * as crypto from crypto-js` work?

Comment: @RyanDsouza, in-order to do `import *`, all modules has to be exported. That's not the case with `crypto-js` if you look at the code for `sha256.js`, https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/sha256.js. They're just defining a function . 
Check out my other answer about how export and import works in node https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript/43951115#43951115