# Difference between export default myVar and export default myFunc()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

Is there any perf difference between:

```
const myVar = myFunc()
export default myVar
```

and:

```
export default myFunc()
```

I prefer the 2nd notation (more concise, less code), but I don't know if it has an impact on performance. Each code loading this module will point to the same reference, or to a new one ?

Comment: It's the same `myFunc()` will only be called once.

Comment: *"Each code loading this module will point to the same reference, or to a new one ?"* Modules are always only evaluated once (the first time they are loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in this case.

You simply use an alias.

So the reference will be the same each time.

Comment: Okey, and is the 2nd considered as a bad practice ? I don't see this often, but I like the idea. Even with `export default function() { ... }`, but seems not so common.

Comment: @soywod The most common (and good, my opinion) practice is to export 1 object from a file, which contents a list of props. So you will have a singleton interface for a file. And all your imports will have the same structure. And they are expandable better. As for exporting only 1 thing for a file it's no a big sence if you use 1st or 2nd, but the better option will be an object with 1 field (for same import/export structure)

Comment: I see it a bit differently. The fact to use default export force yourself to apply the Single Responsibility pattern. I have never more than one export to do by file (except for types in fact, so I use `import myFunc, {MyType} from ...`). That why I often use the default, and that's why I came to this `export default function() { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find really good explanations here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#Using_the_default_export
and
[What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: Link only answers are considered poor quality. It also doesn't seem to address the question.

Comment: I know how import / export works, this is not answering my question.

Comment: @soywod Apologies then, note taken.