# JS - default() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to run a plugin that throws me the exception `require(...).default is not a function`. The bin file is pretty simple:

```
'use strict';

require = require('esm')(module /*, options*/);
console.log('BANGBANG')
require('../src/main.js')
  .default()
  .parse(process.argv.slice(2));
```

My file.js is pretty simple:

```
export default main;

function main(cwd) {
  awesome code
}
```

What is wrong on my export `default`?

edit:

It works if i switch to:

'use strict';

```
require = require('esm')(module /*, options*/);
console.log('BANGBANG')
require('../src/main.js')()
  .parse(process.argv.slice(2));
```

Not sure if it's the "right" way.

Comment: look at the main.js that is required. Does it export a default function?

Comment: `default` is a keyword. To call your function, use `require('../src/main.js')(param)`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117231/5734311

Comment: Please tell us what module system you are using. There seems to be a difference how this is implemented between different environments (and even different version of the same environment) like nodejs, reactjs, etc

Comment: @NineBerry I'm using Node 8.10 and NPM 6.4.1

Comment: You are using "esm" as a module manager while Nodejs actually already comes with its own module manager and additionally supports native JavaScript modules. Why do you mix that stuff?

Comment: Not sure! It's a dependency on internet - they use it to build react components (something like plugins). I'm trying to fix it because I really need to use it.

Comment: Are there special requirements like for example should the modules be used both on the server (in nodejs) and in the browser?