# Understanding export statement in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I am coming from React and Vue frankly seems to be way different to me even from Javascript prospective.

From the boiler plate code (**HelloWorld.vue**), Say we have the following code snippet

```
 <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <p>
          For a guide and recipes on how to configure / customize this project,<br />
          check out the
          <a href="https://cli.vuejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener"
            >vue-cli documentation</a
          >.
        </p>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;

</style>
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend how does our export default knows **What** we need to export

Since the question was marked closed due to duplicate, Sharing the difference between the both

Consider, In case of react (or take it as any function) if we created a function

```
const someFunc = () => (
   <div> 
   <h1> Test Component </h1>
   </div>
)

export default someFunc
```

Here i am exporting my somefunc which I can import and use it with whatever way I want in other component

```
import Whatever from "./location"
```

But in the above Vue snippet, I cannot comprehend the significance of

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
};
```

What is the significance of exporting this object?

Also, where would If suppose I need to will I write my functions, class?

Comment: It knows what to export because it immediately follows the words `export default`. Everything in the `{}` gets exported as the default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is "export default" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: @ceejayoz edited.

Comment: It's hard to say what you mean by "significance", but the significance is the same as exporting any function or object in JavaScript. You're creating an encapsulated piece of code with its own properties and functions. You can include additional functions on the `methods` property, or import as helper functions. If you want to you can also write functions inside of the script tags above the export.

Answer (score 1):

Everything inside the curly braces on `export default {}` including methods and data will be exported, and can be imported using `import` like in your example on React

```
import Whatever from "./location"
```

Just to answer your question

```
Also, where would If suppose I need to will I write my functions, class?
```

Methods and other data can be included inside the curly braces on `export default {}`. For example,

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
      message: {
        type: String
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        // put any data here, e.g.,
        isVueDeveloper: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // put any methods here, e.g.,
      firstMethod() {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```