# Error Signing in with google & firebase in expo?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, google-signin

I am trying to sign my user with firebase using Expo google api, but after successfully retrieving the result from :

`Expo.Google.logInAsync`

And I got an undefined credentials from :

`var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken,accessToken);`

with this error

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating_firebase.default.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential'`

this is my firebase config file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth'

var config = {
  apiKey: "fqsdfdsqfdsqdfqsdfqsdf",
  authDomain: "test.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "test",
  storageBucket: "test.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1321564621"
  };
 const Firebase =  firebase.initializeApp(config);
 //const db = firebase.firestore();
export default Firebase;
```

action/auth/index.js :

```
import * as Types from "../Types";
import common from "../../common";
import moment from "moment";
import Firebase from "../../config/firebase";
import Reactotron from "reactotron-react-native";
import { Base64 } from "js-base64";
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import * as Expo from "expo";
import { AccessToken, LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk';    
...
return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: Types.LOADING });
    try {
      const result = await Expo.Google.logInAsync({
        androidClientId: common.API.androidClientId,
        //iosClientId: YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE,  <-- if you use iOS
        scopes: ["profile", "email"],
        behavior: "web"
      });
      if (result.type === "success") {


        var { user, name, photoUrl, accessToken, idToken} = result;


        //var credential = googleProvider.credential(idToken,accessToken);
        //var credential = Firebase.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(idToken,accessToken);
        //Reactotron.log("this is our credentials", credential);
        let userCollection = [];
        let checked = false;
        //const currentUser = await Firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
```

> packages:

```
"expo-cli" :"2.20.10",
"firebase": "5.9.3",
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `import` it properly.

```js
import Firebase from "./path in firebase"
...

const credential = Firebase.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(idToken, accessToken);
```

Comment: the path is correct the import is from the config file

Comment: Your `export default` is `Firebase` but you are using `firebase`.

Comment: this answers your statement : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034400/9724596

Comment: Yes. That's why you have to use it like my answer.

Comment: the error is  `_firebase.default.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential is not a function. (In '_firebase.default.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(idToken, accessToken)', '_firebase.default.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential' is undefined)]`

Comment: I didn't understand you ?

Comment: I have edited my post; I have added my signinwithgoogle action

Comment: Where is the import part?