# Putting a method in a separate file (ES6 module)

Tags: javascript, class, methods, module, es6-class

I want to be able to put a method of a class in a separate file but I can't work out how to do it.

This is what I am thinking at the moment, but it doesn't work:

index.js:

```js
import Person from "./Person.js";

let billy = new Person("Billy");
billy.sayName();
```

Person.js:

```js
import sayName from "./sayName.js";

class Person{
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }
}

Person.prototype.sayName = sayName;

export default Person;
```

sayName.js:

```js
//I get an error: 'thread 'main' has overflowed its stack'
export default function sayName () {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

Comment: [An arrow function can never be a method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31095710/1048572). Please show us how you tried to use the regular function.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. When I tried to do it as a regular function I did this:
`export default function sayName(){ console.log(this.name); }`

Comment: It should be: `export default function () { console.log(this.name); }` https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117231/13745258

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann I don't think it makes a difference, I still get the same error anyway.

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann There's nothing wrong with naming the function

Comment: @TheWizardBear I cannot reproduce the issue. Do you get a stack trace to see which function recursively called itself?

Comment: I created a sandbox and that also seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/class-inheriting-lz9tm

Comment: Huh, yeah you're right. I think the issue is somewhere else. ‍♀️Sorry about this.

Comment: I think I found the problem. My method name was `toString`, so it was having some problems competing with the default behaviour.