# how to import and export function in express js with es

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, import, export

I'm trying to export some functions from a module and import the in other one like that :

```
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'

const saltRounds = 10

function hashPassword(password) {
    let passwordHash = bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
    return passwordHash
}

function verifyPassword(password, passwordHash) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash)

}

function randomTokenString() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(40).toString('hex')
}

function generateJwtToken(user) {
    return jwt.sign({ sub: user.id, id: user.id }, config.secret, { expiresIn: '15m' })
}

export default  { hashPassword, verifyPassword, randomTokenString, generateJwtToken }
```

***import***

```
import { hashPassword, verifyPassword, randomTokenString } from '../helpers/bcrypt.helper.js'
```

I got this error :

> SyntaxError: The requested module '../helpers/bcrypt.helper.js' does
> not provide an export named 'hashPassword'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't export multiple defaults, if you want to export multiple functions then just add the `export` keyword before the function definition

```js
export function hashPassword(password) {
    let passwordHash = bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
    return passwordHash
}

export function verifyPassword(password, passwordHash) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash)

}
```

see more
[What is "export default" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also export like this:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const saltRounds = 10
module.exports = {
    hashPassword: (password) => {
        let passwordHash = bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds)
        return passwordHash
    },

    verifyPassword: (password, passwordHash) => {
        return bcrypt.compareSync(password, passwordHash)
    },

    randomTokenString: () => {
        return crypto.randomBytes(40).toString('hex')
    },

    generateJwtToken: (user) => {
        return jwt.sign({ sub: user.id, id: user.id }, config.secret, { expiresIn: '15m' })
    }
}
```