# How can i export something on react.js

Tags: reactjs

I need to import "Item" and i used that;

import Item from './Item'
But there is a "Attempted import error" mistake => Attempted import error: './Item' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Item').
I added the "Item" under the header class;

```
 </Header>
  <Items>
  {items.map(item=>(<Item></Item>)
  )}
  </Items>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "export default" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript)

Comment: Could you include the code where you define `Item`?

Comment: There is no `import` or `export` in the code you have provided.  Please provide an [mre].

Answer (score 1):

You must export the Item component that you can import the Item component elsewhere. A example:

Item.js:

```
function Item() {
    return (
        <div>
            // Item stuff
        </div>
    )
}
    
export default Item;
```

**Note:** the important here is the `export default Item;`. So that you can import the Item component in other components with `import Item from './ItemPath';`. Of course you must set the right path to your Item component.

Example.js:

```
import Item from './ItemPath';

function Example() {
    return (
        <div>
            </Header>
            <Items>
            { items.map((item) => (
                <Item>Some item</Item>
            )}
            </Items>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Item component does not export any default code
use  something like  `import {Item}  from './Item` or inside ITem File
use something like   `export default ITem`
you can read more [import-export](https://javascript.info/import-export)