# Are import aliases possible using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Today I am using import aliasing to change the name of an import in React:

```
import { Something as SomethingElse } from 'somewhere';
```

However, after switching this file over to TypeScript, the same thing doesn't seem possible. Only after removing the alias am I able to use the import:

```
import Something from 'somewhere';
```

Is it possible to use an import alias in TypeScript?

Comment: The Typescript docs say that this should be possible: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/modules.html#additional-import-syntax What specific error is it causing?

Comment: I am trying to import a package and the specific error is: `Module '"react-tsparticles"' has no exported member 'Particles'. Did you mean to use 'import Particles from "react-tsparticles"' instead?`. I find it strange because it works in JavaScript (.jsx) but once I changed the file extension (.tsx), it no longer works.

Comment: Is `Particles` the "Something" or the "SomethingElse" in your example?

Comment: Sorry should have said that, it is the `Something` in the example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's a default export, so you could just name it whatever you want:

```
import SomethingElse from 'somewhere';
```

These *default* exports are written like:

```
export default ...
```

and you can check out some other explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117160/what-is-export-default-in-javascript).

You may also be interested in the options [`allowSyntheticDefaultImports`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports) and [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) if you can't get it to work.